# Are logical nodes responsible for a continuous range of keys or a random set of keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I was reading [the DynamoDB whitepaper.](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/files/amazon-dynamo-sosp2007.pdf) In it, it is explained how keys obtained from a hash function create a (circular) range. Then, logical nodes are responsible for continuous segments of that range.

> Dynamo’s partitioning scheme relies on consistent hashing to
> distribute the load across multiple storage hosts. In consistent
> hashing [10], the output range of a hash function is treated as a
> fixed circular space or “ring” (i.e. the largest hash value wraps
> around to the smallest hash value). Each node in the system is
> assigned a random value within this space which represents its
> “position” on the ring. Each data item identified by a key is assigned
> to a node by hashing the data item’s key to yield its position on the
> ring, and then walking the ring clockwise to find the first node with
> a position larger than the item’s position.

However, under *Uniform Load Distribution*, some strategies are detailed:

> Strategy 1: T random tokens per node and partition by token value
>
> Strategy 2: T random tokens per node and equal sized partitions

So then these tokens(which I'm assuming are keys?) are distributed randomly to nodes?

So logical nodes are responsible for a continuous range of keys or a random set of keys?

Comment: Note that this isn't a "DynamoDB" whitepaper.  It is a paper from 2007 about a predecessor system, called "Dynamo."  [*"Amazon DynamoDB is based on the principles of Dynamo"*](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2012/01/amazon-dynamodb.html) but to exactly what extent is not specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've just the read paper, I'm no expert.

I understand tokens and keys to both occupy key space (i.e. position on the key ring), however they are not the same thing.

> Dynamo uses the concept of “virtual nodes”. A virtual node looks like
>   a single node in the system, but each node can be responsible for more
>   than one virtual node. Effectively, when a new node is added to the
>   system, it is assigned multiple positions (henceforth, “tokens”) in
>   the ring.

So, in the "basic consistent hashing algorithm" approach, you take each node in your system and randomly assign it a position in the key ring. Therefore each node is responsible for a single continuous range in key space. A wedge of the circle if you will.

The authors note this has some problems around uniformity of access. So instead they came up with a "variant of the consistent hashing algorithm".

In the alternative scheme each node is given a set of 'Tokens'. A token is a virtual node. Conceptually you can imagine lots of small pieces of key space, taken from all around the ring, and assigned to the node. Or in my head - lots of tiny wedges from all around the circle.

In the actual scheme they went for, each virtual node (token) is a continuous set of keys. However each actual node has multiple non-continuous virtual nodes.

Therefore each node has many sections of continuous key space, but taken from all over the total key space. Not quite random and not quite continuous either!